# ActiveSupport::Concern, has_secure password not update some columns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Recoverable` module for my `Customer` model. `Customer` model using `has_secure` method for authentication. Here is the `Customer` model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Recoverable

  ##
  # Validations
  validates :email, format: { with: REGEX_EMAIL }, allow_nil: false, allow_blank: false
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :email


  has_secure_password

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :password_digest_changed?
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :password_digest_changed?

end
```

And here is the `Recoverable` module:

```
# encoding: utf-8

module Recoverable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def reset_password!(new_password, new_password_confirmation)
    self.password = new_password
    self.password_confirmation = new_password_confirmation
    if valid?
      self.reset_password_token = nil
      self.reset_password_sent_at = nil
    end
    save
  end
end
```

My problem is after `reset_password` called `reset_password_token`, `reset_password_sent_at` are not null. It's not set to null. Update query is not set below columns. Why? Am I miss something? If you need more info let me know.

My environments: I'm using Rails 4 app.

**UPDATE 1**
When I puts self.inspect I get following outputs:

```
#<Customer id: 79, email: "milk@yahoo.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$U2knjpm5LF1V/sgXag0DcOpgZWHSpLw8nfCy4U8D57s6...", created_at: "2013-05-11 11:55:34", updated_at: "2013-05-16 10:04:45", reset_password_sent_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PbUhgSPvQZWXflT5fA1WhqhHJX3c7NMapg6eeDQvpBI=", "token"=>"fiMXi2_4cYCHsFMop9TJBL2Qeqc41xWhHA", "q"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, q
  Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."reset_password_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: password_confirmation
Unpermitted parameters: password
  Customer Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "customers" WHERE ("customers"."email" = 'milk@yahoo.com' AND "customers"."id" != 79) LIMIT 1
----------------------------BEFORE: 
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb593c280 @base=#<Customer id: 79, email: "milk@yahoo.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$/xYeks8yyaCMOFORFLMb1.xR7fxfskW6kHR4S2df/LTK...", store_id: 124, created_at: "2013-05-11 11:55:34", updated_at: "2013-05-16 11:56:52", reset_password_sent_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil>, @messages={}>
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "customers" WHERE ("customers"."email" = 'milk@yahoo.com' AND "customers"."id" != 79) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "customers" SET "password_digest" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "customers"."id" = 79  [["password_digest", "$2a$10$/xYeks8yyaCMOFORFLMb1.xR7fxfskW6kHR4S2df/LTKUI001xu0O"], ["updated_at", Thu, 16 May 2013 19:58:25 ULAT +08:00]]
   (16.5ms)  COMMIT
---------------------------- SAVE: 
true
----------------------------AFTER: 
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0xb593c280 @base=#<Customer id: 79, email: "milk@yahoo.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$/xYeks8yyaCMOFORFLMb1.xR7fxfskW6kHR4S2df/LTK...", store_id: 124, created_at: "2013-05-11 11:55:34", updated_at: "2013-05-16 11:58:25", reset_password_sent_at: nil, reset_password_token: nil>, @messages={}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so finally if your model is not valid after clearing variables you can do that:

```
save(validate: false)
```

It will skip validation and will allow you to save invalid model

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your model is really valid ?
I mean something like

```
if valid? 
  puts "valid"
  self.reset_password_token = nil
  self.reset_password_sent_at = nil
else
  puts self.errors.inspect
end
```

Maybe you have some forgotten validation and you are not going to that block ?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I'm checked. My data is valid. Is it bug?

Comment: maybe you can try instead of self.reset_password_token = nil self.update_column(:reset_password_token, nil) and self.update_column(:reset_password_sent_atm nil)

Comment: I'm tried but no luck. I also use write_attribute but no luck tooo :(

Comment: what is displayed when you are making puts self.inspect ? attributes are changed?

Comment: it have to work! ;) can you do combination puts self.errors.inspect puts self.save and again puts self.errors.inspect ? Maybe there is after_save callback which set that variables for you ?